# C++ time series library (analysis and processing)

Tags: c++, performance, time-series

I'm looking to get Stack Overflowers' advice and suggestion on time-series libraries written in C++, some of the constraints and requirements for the library:

- Performance is very critical
- Capable of handling ***very large*** data sets (1 MB - 100 TB range)
- Various kind of discretization/grouping methodologies
- Basic functionality (n-avg, EMA, smoothing, forecasting, normalization)
- Suitable for use in a multi-threaded environments
- Free or open source preferred, however commercial libraries are welcome
- Libraries capable of delegating to [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit)-based calculations are welcome

Comment: What functions are needed?  FFT?  Trend?  Serial dependence?  Stochastics?

Comment: @wallyk: all the basic statistical ones, n-avg, EMA, some simple correlation analysis, smoothing/windowing, pretty much anything, just trying to get an idea for what is out there...

Comment: what is `very large`: terabytes, petabytes?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: I've updated the question. It seems by the lack of responses there isn't much out there.

Comment: Why do you care what language it is written in ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [IT++](http://itpp.sourceforge.net/devel/index.html) ?
The [documentation](http://itpp.sourceforge.net/current/index.html) and [feature list](http://sourceforge.net/apps/wordpress/itpp/it-features/) are quite compelling and applicable, given your question.  Its development may have stalled, but is the primary C++ time series / signal processing library that is open source that I know of.

Otherwise, for straight-up linear algebra, both [Armadillo](http://arma.sf.net) and [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) are good and actively maintained, and Armadillo can even be used along with IT++.

Last but not least, consider R and Octave both of which can also be extended with C++ code (see [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) for the R/C++ interface, and [RcppArmadillo](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.armadillo.html) for an R/C++/Armadillo interface.

Answer (score 2):

I really think that the following link might help.

[old cronos](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~abrock/oldcronos/)

It is open source and under the GPL license.

Comment: This is link only answer. Please add some information here.

Comment: sadly, the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

[Intel's IPP](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp/) might be worth looking at.

Comment: I was about to suggest either MKL or arBB from Intel, but this looks great too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't despair!

There is stuff out there, but your question is very general, in the sense that you might need several libraries to achieve your result.

1. GSL (GNU Scientific Library) has statistical functions...
2. FFTW (Fastest Fourier Transform in the West) lives up to its name, but if it meets your requirements... I don't know.

There are others, but don't know them. Some of the algorithms you need are in the C++ standard library, or aren't very hard to code as fast as possible like n-avg). GPU offloading is going to be difficult (especially due to the data set size, which will probably make it a bad idea, multi-threading is a possibility in the abovementioned libraries.

Comment: The GSL is nice, but more bare-bones that what was asked here: not C++. no multithreading support, and does not really contain any time series features.

Comment: Dirk: as I said in my answer, the question is way too general to give anything better. And GSL can cope with FFT's (which is 75% of "time series features" anyone could want).

Comment: For the record, I disagree on FFT being 75% of time series analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are looking for a library, suitable for some algorithmic trading application, you can take a look at [Ta-Lib](http://www.ta-lib.org/index.html). It is written in C++. I do not know if it is capable of handling very large datasets but it is performant.

Comment: Ta-lib is written in C, not C++, and uses so pretty harsh C idioms such as fixed-sized arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There is limited free code to do what you need. In fact there is limited code in general, free or commercial.
[NAG Time series chapter](http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/cl/nagdoc_cl09/xhtml/G13/g13conts.xml#g13) does some of what you need, but it's commercial software and written C. I would argue that for this sort of thing C++ has relatively little advantages over C (up to debate obviously, but there is more Fortran than C for this sort of problems, that says it all...)

There is some beta of a GPU aware NAG. In fact they are doing [lots of work on that](http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/gpus/)

Answer (score 0):

[Vhayu](http://www.vhayu.com) has all the interesting stuff, amazing performance and compression abilities by former Intel engineers.  Unfortunately having been bought by Reuters and now part of Thomson Reuters you aren't going to learn anything from their website:

http://thomsonreuters.com/products_services/financial/financial_products/a-z/enterprise_platform_for_velocity_analytics/

So have a little better luck with the Internet Archive version:

http://web.archive.org/web/20090322192616/http://www.vhayu.com/?

Answer (score -2):

You might want to take a look at [q](http://kx.com/q) (AKA kdb+).

It's not a library, and it's not C++, but it does a lot of that kind of stuff.

Comment: Specifically Because q is pretty much THE time series database. Although database isn't quite the right word. It does everything the op asked for.

Comment: Not the best of links, anything more informative like http://kx.com/products.php ?

Comment: If you've ever "really" used kdb - you quickly realize that there's more marketing and fluff than an actual working system. I know a lot of people that have been burnt by the k-con.

Comment: yet i know people/orgs that make many many £m using it... guess it just depends on how you use the tools at your disposal!...